# Efficiently create data.frames for a changing number of input csv files with identical 'tidy' format and size

Tags: r, csv, dplyr, tidyverse, tidy

I can't figure out how to:

1. efficiently create, with `rbind` or another way, a `data.frame` compiling csv-derived `data.frame`s, whose number varies for different projects. Or similarly:
2. efficiently create a `data.frame` of the difference between a csv-derived "baseline scenario" 's  values and those of the rest of the csv-based alternative scenarios.

The csvs are timeseries of hydrologic model output, already in long, 'tidy' format and they're identical in format, size, and order -- there's just different numbers of them for different projects. There's always at least two, a baseline and an alternative, but there's usually quite a few. Eg, Project A might have four csvs/scenarios and Project B might have thirty csvs/scenarios.

I'm hoping to have one code template that will efficiently accommodate projects with any number of scenarios.  Without an efficient way, I'm needing to add or delete quite a few lines to match the number of scenarios I have on an sub-daily basis, so it's a time-consuming step I'd like to avoid.  After `df` and `df_diff` are created, both are used for later summaries and plots.

I'll manually enter the names of the scenarios as they always differ, eg:

```
library(dplyr)
scenarios <- c("baseline", "alt1", "alt1b", "no dam")
```

`length(scenarios)` will always match the number of CSVs I have for a given project.

Read in the csvs (one csv for each scenario) and keep them unmodified for later, separate processing:

```
#In my case these csv#s are from a separate file's list of csvs,
#eg csv1 <- read.csv("baseline.csv")
#   csv2 <- read.csv("alt1.csv"), etc - all tidy monthly timeseries of many variables

#For reproducibility, simplyfying:

csv1 <- data.frame("variable" = "x", "value" = 13)  #baseline scenario                                                    
csv2 <- data.frame("variable" = "x", "value" = 5)   #"alternative 1"
csv3 <- data.frame("variable" = "x", "value" = 109) #"alternative 1b"
csv4 <- data.frame("variable" = "x", "value" = 11)  #"dam removal"
#csv5 <- data.frame("variable" = "x", "value" = 2.5) #"100 extra flow for salmon sep-dec" 
#...
#csv30 <- data.frame("variable" = "x", "value" = 41) #"alternative H3"
```

Copy the csvs and connect data to scenario:

```
baseline  <- csv1 %>% mutate(scenario = as.factor(paste0(scenarios[1])))
scen2     <- csv2 %>% mutate(scenario = as.factor(paste0(scenarios[2])))
scen3     <- csv3 %>% mutate(scenario = as.factor(paste0(scenarios[3])))
scen4     <- csv4 %>% mutate(scenario = as.factor(paste0(scenarios[4])))  

df <- rbind(baseline, scen2, scen3, scen4)   #data.frame #1 I'm looking for.
#eg, if csv1-csv30 were included, how to compile in df efficiently, w/o needing the "scen" lines?
```

[image]

There are 4 scenarios in this case so `df$scenario` has 4 levels. To get here.

Now for the second "difference" `data.frame`:

```
bslnevals <-  baseline  %>% select(value)
scen2vals <-  scen2     %>% select(value)
scen3vals <-  scen3     %>% select(value)
scen4vals <-  scen4     %>% select(value)

scen2diff  <- (scen2vals -  bslnevals)  %>% transmute(value_diff = value, 
              scenario_diff = as.factor(paste0(scenarios[2], " - baseline"))) %>% 
              data.frame(scen2)  %>% select(-value, -scenario)
scen3diff  <- (scen3vals -  bslnevals)  %>% transmute(value_diff = value, 
              scenario_diff = as.factor(paste0(scenarios[3], " - baseline"))) %>% 
              data.frame(scen3) %>% select(-value, -scenario)
scen4diff  <- (scen4vals -  bslnevals)  %>% transmute(value_diff = value, 
              scenario_diff = as.factor(paste0(scenarios[4], " - baseline"))) %>% 
              data.frame(scen4) %>% select(-value, -scenario)

df_diff <- rbind(scen2diff, scen3diff, scen4diff) #data.frame #2 I'm looking for.
#same as above, if csv1 - csv30 were included, how to compile in df_diff efficiently, w/o
#needing the  "scen#vals" and "scen#diff" lines?
```

[image]

```
rm(baseline, scen2, scen3, scen4) #declutter - now unneeded (but csv1, csv2, etc orig csv#s needed later)
rm(bslnevals, scen2vals, scen3vals, scen4vals) #unneeded
rm(scen2diff, scen3diff, scen4diff) #unneeded
```

With 4 scenarios, there are 3 differences from the baseline so `df_diff$scenario` has 3 levels.

So, if I had 4 csvs (1 baseline, 3 alternatives) or maybe 30 CSVs (1 baseline, 29 alternatives), I tried to write functions and for loops that would assign `scen2` and `scen3` ...`scen28` , and `scen2diff`, `scen3diff`...`scen28diff` etc, variables dynamically, but I failed. So, I'm looking for a way that works and that doesn't need much modification when applied to a project with any number of scenarios. I'm looking just to create `df` and `df_diff` in a clean way for a user, for however many scenarios (ie csvs) happen to be given to me or them for a given project.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the scenario name related to the csv file's name by any chance?

Comment: Thanks @Jack Brookes, they are, but they can be long and or busy with all sorts of characters  with metadata that can be a little long or not straightforward enough to the audience when it comes to plot legends.  But I'm open to anything - I could always change the csv names as they come to me and keep track of those details separately or in another column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test with your case but this may be a good starting point for refactoring your code. I use `case_when` to generate rules to map the name of the CSV file to a scenario. I subtract the baseline value from the value in each scenario.

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

baseline_df <- read_csv("baseline.csv") %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number())

# list all csv files (in current directory), then read them all, and row-bind them.
# use case_when to apply rules to change filenames to "scenarios" (grepl to check presence of string)
# join with baseline df (by scenario row number) for easy subtracting.
# calculate differences values.
# remove baseline-baseline rows (diff is 0)

diff_df <- list.files(path = getwd(), pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE) %>% 
  tibble(filename = .) %>%
  mutate(data = map(filename, read_csv)) %>%
  unnest() %>% 
  mutate(scenario = case_when(
    grepl("baseline", filename) ~ "baseline",
    grepl("alternative1", filename) ~ "alt1",
    grepl("alternative2", filename) ~ "alt2",
    grepl("dam_removal", filename) ~ "no dam",
    TRUE ~ "other"
  )) %>% 
  group_by(scenario) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  left_join(baseline_df, by = "id", suffix = c("_new", "_baseline")) %>% 
  mutate(Value_diff = Value_new - Value_baseline) %>% 
  filter(scenario != "baseline")
```

Comment: thanks again @Jack Brookes, useful info for sure and I'll certainly play with these new tricks for me but I'm going to leave the question open for other ideas, for efficient ways to get both `df_diff` and `df` based on the structure I already have: a `scenarios` vector that's the same length as number of csvs.

Comment: actually, can you expand on how to list the csvs? I tried as you have but `object filename not found`. because sometimes there are quite a few, it's not straightforward to point to a, say `csv_list.r` somehow, is it? thank you.

Comment: My line of code `list.files("/", pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE)` lists all CSV files in the current directory.

Comment: baseline.csv, alt.csv:`diff_df <- list.files("/", pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE) %>% 
  map_dfr(read_csv, .id = "filename") %>% 
  mutate(scenario = case_when(
    grepl("baseline", filename) ~ "baseline",
    grepl("alt", filename) ~ "alt",
    TRUE ~ "other"
  )) %>% 
  group_by(scenario) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  left_join(baseline_df, by = "id", suffix = c("_new", "_baseline")) %>% 
  mutate(value_diff = value_new - value_baseline) %>% 
  filter(scenario != "baseline")`  `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: object 'filename' not found.`

Comment: I will update my answer - `map_dfr(... .id)` does not work how I expected. edit: updated

Comment: `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: object 'value_new' not found.`

Comment: At this point I&#39;m not sure what your column names are. I am assuming the name 'value'. See what your dataframe looks like after the left_join and I'm sure it will be clear

Comment: I appreciate all the help and was off with case as it is "Value", but I get the same, and an unpopulated data frame for each pipe. If you have time,  small two-variable each baseline.csv & alt.csv are here: https://gist.github.com/dbo99/dd74cef5935c68cbf734529d4846b5c4

Comment: Answer updated, issue was `list.files` path argument. Now works, you may want to remove unnecessary column with `select`.

Comment: Works for me too and will do. Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169808/discussion-between-doconnor-and-jack-brookes).